# Mostrar un metodo APIRest con Eddystone Android

Tags: android-studio, api, mongodb

Escontre esta aplicacion de Eddystone [Ejemplo Beacon](https://github.com/davigonz/SG-Bootcamp-Beacons) en el metodo didRangeBeaconsInRegion coloque un mensaje para que cuando detecte cualquier region beacon me muestre ese mensaje, ahora lo que quiero es que en vez de mostrar ese mensaje me muestre un metodo.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, BeaconConsumer, RangeNotifier
{

    protected final String TAG = MainActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName();;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private static final long DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD_MS = 6000l;
    private static final String ALL_BEACONS_REGION = "AllBeaconsRegion";

    // Para interactuar con los beacons desde una actividad
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;

    // Representa el criterio de campos con los que buscar beacons
    private Region mRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getStartButton().setOnClickListener(this);
        getStopButton().setOnClickListener(this);

        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // Fijar un protocolo beacon, Eddystone en este caso
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

        ArrayList<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<>();

        mRegion = new Region(ALL_BEACONS_REGION, identifiers);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (view.equals(findViewById(R.id.startReadingBeaconsButton))) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                // Si los permisos de localización todavía no se han concedido, solicitarlos
                if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    askForLocationPermissions();

                } else { // Permisos de localización concedidos

                    prepareDetection();
                }

            } else { // Versiones de Android < 6

                prepareDetection();
            }

        } else if (view.equals(findViewById(R.id.stopReadingBeaconsButton))) {

            stopDetectingBeacons();

            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            // Desactivar bluetooth
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Activar localización y bluetooth para empezar a detectar beacons
     */
    private void prepareDetection() {

        if (!isLocationEnabled()) {

            askToTurnOnLocation();

        } else { // Localización activada, comprobemos el bluetooth

            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

                showToastMessage(getString(R.string.not_support_bluetooth_msg));

            } else if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                startDetectingBeacons();

            } else {

                // Pedir al usuario que active el bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {

            // Usuario ha activado el bluetooth
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                startDetectingBeacons();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) { // User refuses to enable bluetooth

                showToastMessage(getString(R.string.no_bluetooth_msg));
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Empezar a detectar los beacons, ocultando o mostrando los botones correspondientes
     */
    private void startDetectingBeacons() {

        // Fijar un periodo de escaneo
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD_MS);

        // Enlazar al servicio de beacons. Obtiene un callback cuando esté listo para ser usado
        mBeaconManager.bind(this);

        // Desactivar botón de comenzar
        getStartButton().setEnabled(false);
        getStartButton().setAlpha(.5f);

        // Activar botón de parar
        getStopButton().setEnabled(true);
        getStopButton().setAlpha(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        try {
            // Empezar a buscar los beacons que encajen con el el objeto Región pasado, incluyendo
            // actualizaciones en la distancia estimada
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(mRegion);

            showToastMessage(getString(R.string.start_looking_for_beacons));

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Se ha producido una excepción al empezar a buscar beacons " + e.getMessage());
        }

        mBeaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
    }


    /**
     * Método llamado cada DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD_MS segundos con los beacons detectados durante ese
     * periodo
     */
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

        if (beacons.size() == 0) {
            showToastMessage(getString(R.string.no_beacons_detected));
        }

            showToastMessage("Bienvenido");

        /*for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            showToastMessage("Hola! hemos detectado un Beacon");
        }*/
    }

    private void stopDetectingBeacons() {

        try {
            mBeaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(mRegion);
            showToastMessage(getString(R.string.stop_looking_for_beacons));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Se ha producido una excepción al parar de buscar beacons " + e.getMessage());
        }

        mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();

        // Desenlazar servicio de beacons
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);

        // Activar botón de comenzar
        getStartButton().setEnabled(true);
        getStartButton().setAlpha(1);

        // Desactivar botón de parar
        getStopButton().setEnabled(false);
        getStopButton().setAlpha(.5f);
    }

    /**
     * Comprobar permisión de localización para Android >= M
     */
    private void askForLocationPermissions() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.location_access_needed);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.grant_location_access);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    prepareDetection();
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.funcionality_limited);
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.location_not_granted) +
                            getString(R.string.cannot_discover_beacons));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Comprobar si la localización está activada
     *
     * @return true si la localización esta activada, false en caso contrario
     */
    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean networkLocationEnabled = false;

        boolean gpsLocationEnabled = false;

        try {
            networkLocationEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            gpsLocationEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Excepción al obtener información de localización");
        }

        return networkLocationEnabled || gpsLocationEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Abrir ajustes de localización para que el usuario pueda activar los servicios de localización
     */
    private void askToTurnOnLocation() {

        // Notificar al usuario
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage(R.string.location_disabled);
        dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.location_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private Button getStartButton() {
        return (Button) findViewById(R.id.startReadingBeaconsButton);
    }

    private Button getStopButton() {
        return (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopReadingBeaconsButton);
    }

    /**
     * Mostrar mensaje
     *
     * @param message mensaje a enseñar
     */
    private void showToastMessage (String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

}
```

Este es el programa, quisiera meter este metodo:

```html
private void jsonParse() {

        String url = "http://[ip]:3000/api/product";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String name = employee.getString("name");
                                String picture = employee.getString("picture");
                                String temp = employee.getString("price");
                                String category = employee.getString("category");
                                String description = employee.getString("description");

                                mTextViewResult.append("\n"+name);
                                mTextViewResult2.append("\n"+description);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar a encontrar la manera de poder mostrar este metodo al detectar un beacon.

Anexo mi XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="428dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/startReadingBeaconsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:text="Inicio"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/stopReadingBeaconsButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:text="Detener"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:padding="16dp">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/text1"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                            android:textColor="#000"
                                            android:textSize="18sp"/>

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/text2"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                                            android:textColor="#000"
                                            android:textSize="16sp"/>

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/text3"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                                            android:textColor="#000"
                                            android:textSize="16sp"/>

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/text4"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:textColor="#555"/>

                                </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: en que parte se encuentra el mensaje que mencionas?

Comment: En el método didRangeBeaconsInRegion: showToastMessage("Hola! hemos detectado un Beacon");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estas usando `Volley` no debes tener problema para realizar la petición ya que no provocaría por ejemplo un error del tipo `NetworkOnMainThread`, por lo tanto simplemente llama el método que realizaría la petición:

```
/**
 * Método llamado cada DEFAULT_SCAN_PERIOD_MS segundos con los beacons detectados durante ese
 * periodo
 */
   @Override
   public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

     jsonParse(); 

  }
```

Comment: Lo intente, sin embargo me muestra el mensaje que coloque al detectar un beacon pero la informacion del metodo jsonParse no aparece.

Comment: entonces me parece que tienes un problema al parsear el Json, imprime lo que sucede dentro del método :  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                
            }

Comment: El método JsonParse lo probé con anterioridad, genere otra aplicación con el mismo método y funciono pero no descarto que ese pueda ser mi problema, el método onErrorResponse lo pondria en mi MainActivity o dentro de JsonParse?